# UITableView diffable data source

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, diffabledatasource

How to Create Multiple Section In Tableview Using Diffable DataSource.?

I create Simple TableView using Diffable DataSource But I can't underStand How to Set Multiple Section With Tittle.?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add your sections to your snapshot by calling its `appendSections(_:)` method.

Then you add items to your sections with `appendItems(_:toSection:)`.

Finally, in your class that subclasses `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`, you need to override the method `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)`. In the implementation of this method you can call `snapshot().sectionIdentifiers[section]` to get the section identifier which then lets you return an appropriate title of the section.

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot) has an example that uses a single section, so by providing the second argument to `appendItems` you can target which section should be populated with the given items, i.e:

```swift
enum MySectionType {
   case fruits
   case beverage
}

// Create a snapshot
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<MySectionType, String>()        

// Populate the snapshot
snapshot.appendSections([.fruits, .beverage])
snapshot.appendItems(["", ""], toSection: .fruits)
snapshot.appendItems(["coke", "pepsi"], toSection: .beverage)

// Apply the snapshot
dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
```

If you'd like to provide the section titles, I'd subclass the `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` and override the relevant methods, i.e:

```swift
class MyDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<MySectionType> {

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let sectionIdentifier = self.snapshot().sectionIdentifiers[section]

    switch sectionIdentifier {
      case .fruits:
        return NSLocalizedString("Fruits", "")
      case .beverage:
        return NSLocalizedString("Beverage", "")
    }
  }

}
```